# Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine installation of Flink on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows-10, apache-flink

I am trying to install Flink 1.11.2 on Windows 10. I have also installed Cygwin in order to run the command ./start-cluster.sh and start Flink. I expected to open Flink´s Dashboard through Chrome but it can not be reached. So, I checked the log file and it says that:

"Improperly specified VM option 'MaxMetaspaceSize=268435456
'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."

I also have succesfully installed java version "1.8.0_261".

What would be the problem?

Comment: This is a bug https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@flink.apache.org/msg384764.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
After installing the Linux version of java and setting the java home with the new PATH this issue was resolved